# gnuplot: Projecting axes labels and tics on the xy plane of an splot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, surface

I would like to know if there is a way of projecting the x and y axes labels and tics on the xy plane of an splot using gnuplot.

This example shows what I want:

[image]

which contrasts to what I currently have:

[image]

Note how in the top image the label seems to be "laying" on the xy plane, while in the bottom image it is always perpendicular to the viewer. I am wondering if there is an easy way to do this with gnuplot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "_to lay the x and y axes labels_" ? Do you want to modify the size of the font or to make labels (and tics) parallel to the axis they belong as suggest your `set xlabel rotate parallel`. Could you provide a [mcve] ?

Comment: I added extra info that hopefully clarifies the question.

Comment: I do not want to change the font, but rather change the angles of the plane of the label (and tics). Let me know if it is still unclear. I find it a bit difficult to describe in words. The images explain better what I would like to have.

Comment: The question is clear, but gnuplot cannot project text on a plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question is clear, but gnuplot cannot project text on a plane.

– Christoph Oct 26 '18 at 4:36

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need projected labels on the xy-plane and if you do not take fright of a cumbersome workaround you can try the following.

- gnuplot can project an image on a xy-plane
- create your xy-plane with labels and save it as PNG
- use multiplot to overlay and align two plots

**But here comes the difficulty:** you need to align the two plots perfectly by setting the margins appropriately. I have to admit, I still haven't understood how to align them automatically by some simple calculation instead of tedious fiddling around with the margins manually. Besides that you need to set the size, font and offsets accordingly. See the following code just as a starting point. Improvements welcome. Good luck!

**Code:**

```
### labels projected on xy-plane
reset session

# draw the bottom and save as PNG image
SizeX=500; SizeY=500
set term pngcairo size SizeX,SizeY
set output "tb3DLabelXY.png"

set size square
myMargin = 0.13
set margin screen myMargin, screen 1-myMargin, screen myMargin, screen 1-myMargin
set xrange[-10:10]
set xlabel "Precipitation amount, x" font ",20"
set y2range[-10:10]
set y2label "Precipitation amount, y" font ",20" offset -1.5,0
set y2tics rotate by 90 offset 0,-1
set tics font ",16"
unset ytics
set yrange[0:1]
set grid xtics, y2tics lw 2
plot -1 notitle
set output

reset session
set term wxt size 500,500  # or whatever terminal you have
set view equal xy
set view 60,60

set multiplot
    unset xtics
    unset ytics
    unset ztics
    unset xlabel    
    myMargin = 0.17
    # margins l,r,b,t
    set margins screen myMargin, screen 1-myMargin, screen myMargin, screen 1-myMargin
    set zrange[0:200]
    unset border
    splot 'tb3DLabelXY.png' binary filetype=png  with rgbimage notitle

    set border 4095
    set isosamples 20,20
    set xyplane at -100
    # margins l,r,b,t
    set margins screen 0.255, screen 0.74, screen 0.04, screen 0.81
    set xrange[-10:10]
    set yrange[-10:10]
    set zrange[-100:100]
    set ztics -80,40
    set hidden3d
    splot x*y

unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]